# Confusion regarding bounds on integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

So i have presently seperated a differential equation to shown that $\frac{dp(y)}{p(y)}=-\frac{Mg}{RT(y)}dy$

I would then like to integrate on both sides to solve for $p(y)$, but i am unsure of what bounds that go on the intgeral.

This problem occurs as i am integrating from a height $y$ all the way down to the surface $0$. I would then think that the integrals would look like this:

$\int_y^0 \frac{dp(s)}{p(s)}=\int_y^0 -\frac{Mg}{RT(s)}ds=\frac{Mg}{R} \int_y^0 -\frac{1}{T(s)}ds$

I know that you usually put the greatest bound, in this case $y$, on top, but this should be no problem as my $ds$ are negative, and swapping the bounds will also give a negative out front, so it all works out (?)

I am not completely certain that you can write the integrals like this. They are essentially still supposed to mean $\int \frac{dp(y)}{p(y)}$ and $\frac{Mg}{R} \int -\frac{1}{T(y)}dy$, but with emphasis on the fact that i am taking the integral over a finite period. I would think that when you write the integrals as i have done, you would just insert the $y$ after integrating, giving you the desired 'integrals', and that inserting the 0 would give you the constant so all would be fine and dandy, but i am really not sure...

Putting that aside, i would then evaluate LHS=$\int_y^0 \frac{dp(s)}{p(s)}=ln|p(y)|+k$ and so on. Does anyone knows if what i have done is correct or not?